# Population linear model

Tags: mathematical-modeling, correlation

I have a dataset with 15 people. For each person I have the age and a blood measurement. The relation between the age and the blood measurement is linear.

The plot between the two variables looks like this:
[image]

I would like to make a model in which I can predict the blood measurement given that I know the age. If I have a different dataset and I know the age of those people I can therefore predict their blood measurement.

Can anyone help with that?

Can I use the equation y=ax+b? Would that work for a different population?

Comment: Of course your dataset is awfully small. But if it only an exercise, you could indeed make a linear model. I'm guessing you're using Excel or a similar program to plot the data - I'm sure that there's a functionality to calculate the equation of the line too. Otherwise, you can read this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

Comment: Also, here is some useful math, if you need to calculate it by hand (you can ignore the latter part of the answer because it doesn't apply to your case): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3076868/linear-regression-computation-as-y-ax/3076898#3076898

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I am using Excel and I am able to calculate the intercept and slope of the linear equation y=ax+b.  My question is: If I use that value of intercept (b value) and slope (a value) derived from this dataset can I then substitute  the x-values from a different dataset to predict y?

Comment: I cannot promise that. But you can try it! BTW, is this a school assignment or what's the purpose of this calculation? Is it actual research, or ... ?

Comment: It is not an actual research given the very small sample size. It is a university assuagement  (foundation level)