# Why use regression line instead of the line of best fit?

Tags: statistics

I was researching about the line of best fit and came upon [this](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/252/) article that talked about the regression line. In the beginning, everything seemed similar to the best fit line, but then I came upon this :

[image]

And I can't understand why to go through this when you can simply use:
y=mx+b. Don't they give the same result?

Comment: Is there any difference between the regression line and the line of best fit at all ? If not (what I think) the formula should be equivalent to the other.

Comment: "you can simply use $y = mx + b$" The purpose of linear regression is to figure out the best values of $m$ and $b$ to use when fitting a line $y = mx + b$ to data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use $y=mx+b$, you would need to find out the values of $m$ and $b$. And from the least squares method, the value of $b$ is obtained from the equation you wrote. So they are part of the same method.

Comment: So there is no reason to use the more complex formula?

Comment: More complex than what ?

Comment: @Peter than y=mx+b

Comment: @IBMR What values of $m$ and $b$ do you propose to use?

Comment: I guess you didn't really understand the article you posted. The equation $y=mx+b$ is the final form of the approximant, but you obviously need to figure out what the values of $m$ and $b$ are. The "complex" equation is required to do so. Here is another question, talking about a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3076868/linear-regression-computation-as-y-ax/3076898#3076898

Comment: Oh so it's the derivation of the y=mx+b. I see now, thanks